# prestashop theme MegaShop dose not uploading (shows) some photos

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

i'm using a prestashop 1.6 and MegaShop theme,

until yesterday everything worked properly,

pictures they displayed correctly, and everything was fine.

I didn't change nothing so it is strange.

I have deactivated the slider "Home Slider" and "Sub Banners on homepage" because of problem with photos.

This is what i got when the slider is activated:

[image]

so i get the errors in console like:

```
    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://www.mille-et-une-fouta.fr/modules/tptnsubbanner/images/3fdef06374783c551eccda7f2cb336ff4f8eb649_Coffret%20cadeau%20de%20naissance.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://www.mille-et-une-fouta.fr/modules/tptnhomeslider/images/1cb591825bb72f539ada3d5dab8e8f41fe2c865e_authentique.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://www.mille-et-une-fouta.fr/modules/tptnhomeslider/images/1970776817102812dfdfe5bafb97a922f68b3508_Foutas-personnalisees.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://www.mille-et-une-fouta.fr/modules/tptnhomeslider/images/345fc91dce74fb7b0f8ee69a5231e1c9737b2ed7_LINGE-DE-TOILETTE%20.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://www.mille-et-une-fouta.fr/modules/tptnhomeslider/images/c9d990e33256b3d20c7f4850e4fed658b4a01c37_foutas-nids-dabeille.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://www.mille-et-une-fouta.fr/modules/tptncolbanner/images/d813129dad7ed22e45ee4136a16c2f0a31918e9b_deco%20d%20interieure.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://www.mille-et-une-fouta.fr/modules/tptncolbanner/images/636e73def62348d5bba09ab91885573b9f4bbadf_Les%20duos.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://www.mille-et-une-fouta.fr/modules/smartblog/images/7-home-default.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://www.mille-et-une-fouta.fr/modules/smartblog/images/6-home-default.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://www.mille-et-une-fouta.fr/modules/smartblog/images/5-home-default.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://www.mille-et-une-fouta.fr/modules/smartblog/images/8-home-default.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

here's a picture with the console:

[image]

Here's is a link of my website:
http://www.mille-et-une-fouta.fr

I cannot upload photo to back office,

when im uploading the photos, i get the images with question mark like this:

[image]

Can you please help me with some advice

Thank you in advance for your reply and help Mike.

This is really strange after debugging i found that the image exist on the server but it is not showing correctly

Answer (score -1):

You must permalink settings to default once , and again return to its previous state with this problem will be solved